# Change global variable in express middleware at request level. Block fetch for certain requests

Tags: node.js, express, mocking, fetch

Is it possible to change a global variable (like fetch) at request level in express?

I have this middleware.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(req.headers.host.startsWith('mock.')) {  // e.g. mock.myapp.com
     global.fetch = {};
  }
  next();
});
```

My intention is to block the use of `fetch` in certain requests but allow it in others.

Will this affect subsequent requests?

If it will, how can I apply this change just to the current request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.  It's possible to change global variables in middleware, but it's not practical to do what you're trying to do because node.js can easily have multiple requests in flight at the same time.  So, you can't really change the global environment for just one request that won't affect the other requests being processed at the same time.

You'd literally have to force Express to serialize all request processing (build some sort of input queue) and only have one request being worked on until completion before you start processing the next request. This, of course, would ruin the scalability of node.js.

The "per request" environment is the `req` object.  That's where middleware typically puts things that apply to this request only.

> My intention is to block the use of fetch in certain requests but allow it in others.

Can't really do it that way.

> Will this affect subsequent requests?

Yes.  You will have permanently changed the `global` object.

> If it will, how can I apply this change just to the current request.

I think we will need to know more about the higher level problem you're actually trying to solve and why.  The `req` object is the typical place to put state that is supposed to apply uniquely to this specific request processing because there is a unique `req` object for each request and one request knows nothing about any other request's object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to see if there's a way to block outgoing `http` requests.